# find equation of a plane that is 3d

Tags: multivariable-calculus

how to find equation of a plane passing through the point $(5, 6, 8)$ and parallel to the $xz$-plane.

I know you can use the equation $a(x-x_0)+ b(y-y_0)+ c(z-z_0)=0$.

Do i just plug in and thats it?

Comment: Hi, please use LaTeX next time... thanks

Comment: Yes. That's it. $(5,6,8)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $(a,b,c)$ is the coordinate triple of the vector normal to the $xz$-plane.

Answer (score 1):

A plane parallel to the $x$-$z$ plane has equation of the shape $y=k$.